# Constructing a CW complex with following homology groups

Tags: homology-cohomology, cw-complexes

Construct a CW Complex $X$ with the following homology groups (in coefficiants $\mathbb{Z})$: $H_0(X)=\mathbb{Z}, H_1(X)=\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z_2}, H_2(X)=\mathbb{Z_3}, H_3(X)=\mathbb{Z}, \; $  and $ \; H_n(X)=0 \;$ if $\; n\ge 4$.

Is my construction a correct way to think about these kinds of problems? Any comments/feedback & other methods are welcome.

Let $X^0=e_0$ and let $X^1$ have two 2-cells $e_1^1, e_2^1$ to obtain the wedge of 2 circles. Attach a 2-cell $e_1^2$ to $X^1$ such that $\partial_2(e_1^2)=2e_2^1$. At this point, we have $H_0(X)=\mathbb{Z}$ and $H_1(X)=\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z_2}$. In particular, $H_2(X)=0\; $  since the boundary map $\partial_2$ is injective.

To amend this, we can attach a second 2-cell $e_2^2$ to $X^0$; this necessarily gives $\partial_2(e_2^2)=0$. Thus $\textrm{ker}(\partial_2)\cong\mathbb{Z}$. Attach a 3-cell $e_1^3$ to $X^2$ via $\partial_3(e_1^3)=3e_2^2$ and so $H_2(X)=\mathbb{Z_3}$. Here $H_3(X)=0$.

Similarly, attach a second 3-cell $e_2^3$ to $X^0$ such that $\partial_3(e_2^3)=0$. This gives $H_3(X)\cong\mathbb{Z}.\;$  Let $X=X^n\;$ for $\;n\ge 4$ and so $H_n(X)=0 \;$ for $\; n\ge 4$ and we are done.

Comment: This looks correct. The point is that you know exactly what you want the cellular chain complex to look like, and you know that there are maps between spheres of any prescribed degree, so you can use said maps to attach cells that will give the desired chain complex.

Comment: Awesome, thanks !